# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del navbar en cada una de sus opciones?

Tags: javascript, html, python, css, django

Lo que me gustaría saber es que cuando se seleccione cada una de las opciones del `navbar` me cambie el **color** de fondo tanto del `navbar` como el `footer`, pero que por cada opción del `navbar` me de un color diferente. 
(Todo esto es para aplicarlo a una plantilla de **Django** espero ser lo suficientemente claro)

**HTML con Python**

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
        <!-- Main navbar header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="{% url 'principal:index' %}" class="navbar-brand">
                <div><img alt="Pixel Admin" src={% static 'images/pixel-admin/main-navbar-logo.png' %}></div>
                Eje internacional
            </a>

            <!-- Main navbar toggle -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar-collapse"><i class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars"></i></button>

        </div> <!-- / .navbar-header -->

        <div id="main-navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar-collapse">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'principal:index' %}">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    {% for obj in categorias %}
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ obj.categoria }}</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            {% for subcategoria in obj.subcategoria %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'principal:publicaciones' obj.categoria subcategoria.nombre %}">{{ subcategoria.nombre }}</a></li>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'principal:categorias' %}">Otros</a>
                    </li>

                </ul> <!-- / .navbar-nav -->

                <div class="right clearfix">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right right-navbar-nav">
```

Este es el `div` del `navbar` es el que estoy usando, de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Te que recomiendo que por facilidad en vez de subir una imágen incluyas todo el código, para esto hay un herramienta en el editor de texto al momento de subir tus preguntas. Saludos!